# AWS Lambda Performance Drops Heavily with Increasing of Concurrent Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

In our application (.net core) there is a complex CPU oriented algorithm. It normally takes 2-3 minutes per single execution. Right now we execute this in a background service sequentially. So we only can manage about 25 successful executions per hour which is not enough when there is high demand. Execution in multiple threads also didn't help given this is a highly CPU oriented job. In fact, it gave even worse results with multiple threads.

So I thought of using AWS Lambdas. So I created a Lambda Function capable of executing the logic and it is triggered by an AWS SQS. So whenever I need to execute the logic, a message is pushed to the queue, and Lambda picks and executes it.

When there is only one request Lambda also took 2-3 minutes per execution and that is ok. I have set Lambda's timeout as 15 minutes just in case.

However, the Problem starts when there is a large number of requests (ex: 1000 withing 5 mins). As expected Lambda increases the number of instances. But that eventually drops the performance of all the instances. In fact, almost all of them can't complete the job within the 15-minute timeout.

So I presume all the parallel instances of Lambdas are span out in one/few PCs where they share the same/few CPUs which eventually simulate the condition I initially had with multiple threads. Contrary to my original thought of each instance gets configured memory (Allocated 512 MB. it normally needs less than 180MB) and adequate CPU for it.

The package size is 15Mb. Since cold start time is not a big issue for me, so I think provisioned concurrency also wouldn't help me either (not sure). Besides, It needs to be configured with a particular version which will add lots of hassle during subsequent deployments.

I hope the problem is clear. Has anyone come across something like this or knows how to get over with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify one thing. If you have a single message in SQS, it runs fast. But if you have many, its slow? So your functions fetches 10 messages in the later case probably, and the lambda processes them in the loop?

Comment: When you are receiving 1000 requests...can you see 1000 lambda triggered because in concurrent lambda execution each lambda gets its own cpu and memory? So performance is going to increase

Comment: Try allocating the full 3,008 MB to the Lambda function. This will give you more CPU and it will complete much faster. Your share of the CPU is proportional to the RAM size. Also, as Marcin notes, be sure you are not accidentally processing multiple SQS messages in a batch (or at least take account of this in your calculations). While you are charged more per unit of time for the large RAM size, your process will complete more quickly so the actual cost may be similar.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry I forgot to mention that.  I have set the trigger as just 1 message at t a time.

Comment: Does your func. rely on some external API or db? Maybe the bottleneck is not the lambda, but something that it uses? For example, if a single func. calls external api it works fast. But if you have 1000 functions calling the same api at the same time, it chokes the api server, causing your functions to wait long for responses?

Comment: @ShubhamJain: There wasn't 1000 instances but about 300-400. Yes in the monitoring it showed each has 512 memory allocated.

Comment: @jarmod: Yeah will try doing that as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes Its does. Communicate with the Postgres database. One execution does a few reads and writes. One question: setting reserved concurrency to a value like 10 guarantees that only 10 instances at a time?

Comment: Reserved concurrency: When a function has reserved concurrency, no other function can use that concurrency. Reserved concurrency also limits the maximum concurrency for the function, and applies to the function as a whole, including versions and aliases.

Comment: yes. you can limit number of concurrent lambda invocations using reserved concurrency setting. Check db. Seems as it could be chocking under 1000 concurrent reads and writes?

Comment: @Marcin: Yeah will try that. Even if it can get 10 - 20 instances I should be fine. Just one more question, when using a FIFO queue, It's lambda always process one message at a time, right? the next message picks up after completing the first right?

Comment: For fifo, ordering is only ensured withing same group (message group id). So if you have five groups, only 5 concurrent lambdas will be processing them (one per group).

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I will experiment with the suggestions and put the status here.

Comment: No problem. Let me know what you find out. Its interesting issue.

Comment: @Wijitha we had a similar problem years ago when we were reading from aurora in aws lambda. When we increased the number of process that invokes lambda we noticed spikes in duration. The problem was query (it was using limit/offset) when we were querying the database with limit/offset with multiple concurrent executions - it was choking, then aws lambda was facing timeout. It may be critical to replace outer api call with fake/mock ones and depending on the performance, maybe focus on the query.

Comment: @Marcin, You are correct. The bottleneck is at the DB. I was testing in our test DB server which is Postgres RDS: db.t2.medium (2 VCPU, 4Gig). Now I modified the DB to db.t2.xLarge (4 VCPU, 16Gig) and set the reserved concurrency to 10. Now its looking good where average execution time  per request is 2-3 minutes. Thanks everyone for tips and help.

Comment: @Ersoy, Yeah, that's the case for me as well. Its the DB getting bottleneck. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of the problem, it may be inferred that the bottleneck is not in Lambda or SQS. The root cause of the problem could be with the data access layer.  Adding more parallel threads to access data will only burden the data access layer more. It will therefore reduce the performance.

**Here are the possible solutions that will improve the performance of the data access layer:**

1. Add a cache in front of Database, to handle read requests
2. Increase the memory or machine type for the Database server
3. Move database storage to high performance SSD volume
4. Add read-replicas for database and direct all read requests to the replicas.
5. Switch to AWS Aurora DB, which offers 5x performance boost.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that was the case for me. Its the DB.